# Some boot text still showing regardless of documented 'solutions'

Tags: boot

I am trying to remove all text from the start-up process of the RPi. I have found serveral guides explaining how to do this, and they all say relatively the same thing. [Example.](https://www.pi-supply.com/make/disabling-verbose-boot-mode-raspberry-pi/) Here is my cmdline.txt, according to everything I can find, this should work, however I still am getting about a screens worth of lines on boot up. It should be noted there this is significantly less than what was there initially.

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty3 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait loglevel=3 logo.nologo vt.global_cursor_default=0 quiet
```

Answer (score 1):

A hardware solution: get an HDMI extender or switch with an on-off button, and activate it via GPIO when the Pi is fully booted.

Perhaps it could be possible to simply cut a wire in the HDMI cable which you would then reconnect with a relay. No idea which one though. Cutting the clock will disable the HDMI for sure, but I'm not certain HDMI will work well if you route the clock through a relay.

Answer (score 0):

Anther way to remove most of the text is by enabling the splash screen `sudo raspi-config` then `boot options` then `splash screen`. This wont remove *all* text but will remove all but 20-30 lines and there is probably some way to switch the standard screen for your own if you'd like.

Comment: Thanks. I am working on a minimal install so "The splash screen is not installed so cannot be activated" Do you know what needs to be installed for it to work?

Comment: @gleeson it only works on the GUI version

Comment: Yes, I am using openbox so all of the little things I have to install manually. So I'm asking if you know what package is used for that. Or is it built in to LXDE or one of them only?

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is only on Raspbian

Comment: So used [this](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/custom-boot-up-screen) method to implement a splash screen, however it didn't remove the text in question. Does anyone else have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding these two options to cmdline.txt:

```
plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
loglevel=0
```